# Markdown link ID not recognized

Tags: github, hyperlink, markdown

Hopefully this is a simple problem...

After years of web development and sitting on all sorts of re-usable code I decided to combine everything into a custom CMS - mostly for my own usage. Threw together a git repository, made a README.md file, and... some of the links aren't working.

Here's my git repo: https://github.com/stevendesu/MyCMS

If you scroll to the bottom you'll notice the two links to php.net are posted as text, and further up in the document when I attempted to create links using these ID's it just displayed the markdown.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be all of the whitespace between your urls and the title near the bottom. At the bottom of your README, I removed all of the whitespace (except for a single space to separate them) between the links. The resulting code looked like this:

```
[1]: <http://wordpress.org> "WordPress.org"
[2]: <http://drupal.org> "Drupal (TM)"
[3]: <http://concrete5.org> "concrete5"
[4]: <http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php> "PHP.net: PDO - Introduction"
[5]: <http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php> "PHP.net: PDO - Drivers"
```

Doing so fixed the hotlinks in the paragraphs above.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks! Odd that the links with lots of tabs worked and those with few tabs didn't....